# What is "Custom(CSRCustomLayout)"?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

SharePoint 2013 introduced the CSR technology to render list views and forms. when you go to the list form web part properties you will find new two properties (JS Link and CSR Render Mode), inside the "CSR Render Mode" there is three choices, one of them is **Custom (CSRCustomLayout)** What is this option? and how and when we use it?

[image]

after select:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client Side Rendering was introduced in SharePoint 2013 as a main technique for displaying data, replacing XSLT. CSR is now used by default for displaying data from standard lists (exceptions: Survey and Calendar lists) - including list forms, list views and lists in Quick Edit mode, - and search results.

**Custom Mode**
The custom mode should have been the full-scale CSR mode, where both layout, field captions and field controls are generated with CSR.

Unfortunately, based on my investigation, it seems unlikely that Custom mode was really even tested, because the bugs are very obvious and everywhere :(

So here is what happens if you just switch a list form to Custom mode, via Web Part Properties:[image]

Read Complete Article over here: 
[SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610259/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms)